# Insert with Domain Service Object in server side project

Tags: asp.net, wcf-ria-services, ria, domainservices

I got a basic Silverlight Ria Services solution with 2 projects (Silverlight Client and Asp.net Host) with a Domain Service Class in the Host project.

I can create a new Domain Service object in another class inside the host project, and use the methods generated by Visual Studio.

The query methods of this Domain object works fine retrieving data, but insert methods don't apply to the database, probably cause I didn't submit te operation, as the method "SubmitChanges" does in client project.

Question is: how can I apply insert, delete and update operations with this object in server-side since I'm not coding in Domain Service class, but only using an object of this type?

I've found the method DomainService.Submit, but it requires a ChangeSet that don't know how to provide.

EDIT:

```
//Client Project (Silverlight):
MyDomain domain = new MyDomain();
domain.Products.Add(new Product());
domain.SubmitChanges(); //sucessfull DB insertion 

//Host Project, any new asp.net WebPage: 
MyDomain domain = new MyDomain(); 
domain.InsertProduct(new Product()); //nothing happens in DB 
domain.SubmitChanges(); //don't exist 
domain.Submit(ChangeSet); //don't know how to provide a ChangeSet
```

Comment: Please show us some application code.

Comment: //Client Project:

MyDomain domain = new MyDomain();
domain.Products.Add(new Product());
domain.SubmitChanges(); //sucessfull DB insertion

//Host Project:
MyDomain domain = new MyDomain();
domain.InserProduct(new Product()); //nothing happens in DB
domain.SubmitChanges(); //don't exist

domain.Submit(ChangeSet); //don't know how to provide a ChangeSet

Comment: Please use the edit button to edit the question and add your code inside <pre> <pre> tags

Answer (score 0):

It's done a little bit differently on the server vs. the client.  On the server, from your domain service class, you can use Me.ObjectContext to add and save your entities, e.g.

```
Me.ObjectContext.Products.AddObject(new Product)
Me.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Yeah, but only if you're coding in the Domain Service's class. If you are using a Domain Service Instance, i'ts necessary to write SaveChanges() in a public method in case of being executed. I expected that there would be another way.